# Prime subfield of a field is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

[image]

I can't see the phrase "$F$ contains a subfield isomorphic either $\mathbb{Q}$ (the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z})$ or to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$"
I have the following: By 1 Isomorphism's theorem, $\mathbb{Z}/\ker(\varphi)\simeq Im(\varphi)\subset F$. Now, if $ch(F)=0$ then $\mathbb{Z}/\left\{0\right\}\simeq Im(\varphi)$ but i don't see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $F$ (I only see that a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ us contained in $F$)

In the examples, why the prime subfield of $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: if a field contains integers ($\mathbb Z$), then it contains ratios of integers ($\mathbb Q$) -- it must contain multiplicative inverses and products to be a field

Comment: Consider the field of fractions of that embedded copy of the integers.

Comment: Since an isomorphic copy of Z is contained in the field, the inverses to every element of Z must also exist inside the field since every element in a field has an inverse hence the field of fraction of Z (Q) is contained in the field

Comment: Briefly: if there is a map $D\to K$ from a commutative domain to a field $K$, then by definition there is a map $F(D) \to K$ where $F(D)$ is the field of fractions of $D$. In this case, $F(\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Q$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You acknowledged that, if the characteristic of a field $F$ is $0$, then a copy of $\mathbb Z$, say $\varphi(\mathbb Z)$, is in $F$.

But any $q\in \mathbb Q$ can be expressed as $nm^{-1}$ with $n,m\in \mathbb Z$,

and, because $F$ is a field, $\varphi(n),\varphi(m)\in  F$ means $\varphi(m)^{-1}\in F$ and $\varphi(n)\varphi(m)^{-1}\in F.$

Comment: The point is that $\phi$ extends to a non-zero ring homomorphism from $\Bbb Q$ to $F$. It is then obviously injective.

Comment: @WhatsUp:  I first wrote $\mathbb Z\subset F$, but that's not really true -- $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to a subring of $F$; anyway, feel free to edit my answer or add your own if mine is lacking

Comment: I still have a doubt: If $ch(F)=0$ then $\mathbb{Z}/\left\{0\right\}\simeq Im(\varphi)$ then $\mathbb{Z}\simeq Im(\varphi)$  and it is known that $Im(\varphi)$ is a subfield of $F$ but $\mathbb{Z}$ it not a subfield... What is wrong?